# How to save the array of string in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to save the data in the array of fields uisng node js , but here database is showing with the empty fileds , what i'm doing wrong here. please help me thanks in advance

schema Design:-

```
module.exports = mongoose => {
const Question = mongoose.model(
  "question",
  mongoose.Schema(
    {
      roleType  : { type:String },
      questions : [{ 
          question  : { type:String }, 
          options   : [{ type:String }]
        }]
    })
)    
return Question;
};
```

code:-

```
   const { roleType, question, options }  = req.body
   const questionList = new Question ({     
       roleType: roleType,
       questions: [{
         question:question,
         options: options
       }],
     });
   questionList.save(questionList)
```

postman i'm passing data like this:-

[image]

database is storing like this:-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are destructuring your object in the wrong manner.

`const { roleType, question, options }`. questions and options inside the braces expect the respective properties `question` and `options` in the body object. Since they do not exist, `question` , `options` are undefined.

Simply pass in questions:

```
   const { roleType, questions}  = req.body
   const questionList = new Question ({     
       'roleType': roleType,
       'questions': questions,
     });
   questionList.save(questionList);
```